# how to let appear only one containing child element using show()

Tags: jquery

I have a table, which obviously has multiple `<td>` elements. Every `<td>` contains a `<div class='surprise' style=' display: none;'>`, which I want to appear when hovering over the `<td>`.
Using the code below I was able to show all my `<div>`'s, but I want only that `<div>` which is inside the `<td>` I am hovering over. How can I do that?

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').hover(function () {
        $('.surprise').show();
    },function () {
        $('.surprise').hide();
    });
  });
```

I tried following, without success:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('td').hover(function() {
    $('.surprise').one(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  });
  },function() {
    $('.surprise').one(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<td>` has the child element, use `$(this).find()`, so that it affects only the current `<td>`:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.surprise').show();
    },function () {
        $(this).find('.surprise').hide();
    });
  });
```

Comment: This works great, thank you :-) But when I am hovering quite fast over the several `<td>`s some of the `<div>`'s does not disappear anymore. Do you have an Idea?

Comment: I just recognized that it is a Safari Problem. FF an Chrome have no issues. Any Idea for a workaround on Safari side? btw I am waiting for that mandatory 15min to pass to accept your great answer :-)

Comment: @Lex Awesome. Did you manage to find out why is it not working in Safari? Thanks.

Comment: @Lex Don't worry... There should be some good souls who have already found out a solution. `:)` Search...

Comment: @Lex Welcome to StackOverflow. Enjoy your stay. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be better handled using CSS.

```
td .surprise{
   display:none;
}

td:hover .surprise{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. It even solves the Safari issue mentioned in the comments above. Thank you very much!